# Keeping state of variable mapped from props in functional react component after component redraw

Tags: reactjs

Recently I started learning react and I decided to use in my project functional components instead of class-based. I am facing an issue with keeping state on one of my components.

This is generic form component that accepts array of elements in order to draw all of necessary fields in form. On submit it returns "model" with values coming from input fields.

Everything working fine until I added logic for conditionally enabling or disabling "Submit" button when not all required fields are set. This logic is fired either on component mount using useEffect hook or after every input in form input. After re-render of the component (e.g. conditions for enabling button are not met, so button becomes disabled), component function is fired again and my logic for creating new mutable object from passed props started again, so I am finished with empty object.

I did sort of workaround to make a reference of that mutated object outside of scope of component function, but i dont feel comfortable with it. I also dont want to use Redux for that simple sort of state.

Here is the code (I am using Type Script):

```
//component interfaces: 
export enum FieldType {
  Normal = "normal",
  Password = "password",
  Email = "email"
}

export interface FormField {
  label: string;
  displayLabel: string;
  type: FieldType;
  required: boolean;
}

export interface FormModel {
  model: {
    field: FormField;
    value: string | null;
  }[]
}

export interface IForm {
  title: string;
  labels: FormField[];
  actionTitle: string;
  onSubmit: (model: FormModel) => void;
}

let _formState: any = null;

export function Form(props: IForm) {
  let mutableFormModel = props.labels.map((field) => { return { field: field, value: null as any } });

  //_formState keeps reference outside of react function scope. After coponent redraw state inside this function is lost, but is still maintained outside
  if (_formState) {
    mutableFormModel = _formState;
  } else {
    _formState = mutableFormModel;
  }

  const [formModel, setFormModel] = useState(mutableFormModel);
  const [buttonEnabled, setButtonEnabled] = useState(false);

  function requiredFieldsCheck(formModel: any): boolean {
    let allRequiredSet = true;
    formModel.model.forEach((field: { field: { required: any; }; value: string | null; }) => {
      if (field.field.required && (field.value === null || field.value === '')) {
        allRequiredSet = false;
      }
    })
    return allRequiredSet;
  }

  function handleChange(field: FormField, value: string) {
    let elem = mutableFormModel.find(el => el.field.label === field.label);
    if (elem) {
      value !== '' ? elem.value = value as any : elem.value = null;
    }
    let submitEnabled = requiredFieldsCheck({ model: mutableFormModel });
    setFormModel(mutableFormModel);
    setButtonEnabled(submitEnabled);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setButtonEnabled(requiredFieldsCheck({ model: mutableFormModel }));
  }, [mutableFormModel]);


  function onSubmit(event: { preventDefault: () => void; }) {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit({ model: formModel })
  }

  return (
    <FormStyle>
      <div className="form-container">
        <h2 className="form-header">{props.title}</h2>
        <form className="form-content">
          <div className="form-group">
            {props.labels.map((field) => {
              return (
                <div className="form-field" key={field.label}>
                  <label>{field.displayLabel}</label>
                  { field.type === FieldType.Password ?
                    <input type="password" onChange={(e) => handleChange(field, e.target.value)}></input> :
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleChange(field, e.target.value)}></input>
                  }
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </form>
        {buttonEnabled ?
          <button className={`form-action btn btn--active`} onClick={onSubmit}> {props.actionTitle} </button> :
          <button disabled className={`form-action btn btn--disabled`} onClick={onSubmit}> {props.actionTitle} </button>}
      </div>
    </FormStyle >
  );
}
```

Comment: So your saying you want the state state passed to the parent?

Comment: Not really, component accept callback as last property, this callback accept formModel as argument and i am firing this callback while clicking 'Submit' button. From parent I am receiving model of fields, from which i am creating new object that will be formModel object passed to callback function mentioned above. I added to post above also interfaces that are being used in component.

Comment: You don't have to write a novel in your question. Simply state what's wrong in a sentence or two (as you have) and create an online sandbox that showcases the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So there is quite a lot going on with your state here.

Instead of using a state variable to check if your button should be disabled or not, you could just add something render-time, instead of calculating a local state everytime you type something in your form.

So you could try something like:

```
   <button disabled={!requiredFieldsCheck({ model: formModel })}>Click me</button>
```

or if you want to make it a bit cleaner:

```
   const buttonDisabled = !requiredFieldsCheck({model: formModel});

   ...
   return <button disabled={buttonDisabled}>Click me</button>
```

If you want some kind of "caching" without bathering with useEffect and state, you can also try useMemo, which will only change your calculated value whenever your listeners (in your case the formModel) have changes.

```
const buttonDisabled = useMemo(() => {
   return !requiredFieldsCheck({model: formModel});
}, [formModel]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep value in that particular case, I've just used useRef hook. It can be used for any data, not only DOM related. But thanks for all inputs, I've learned a lot.

Comment: You posted an answer to your own question, which isn't an actual answer, but more of a comment. Next time, better post a comment to reply to answers, or (even better) add your actual solution in code here so others may learn from your endeavours! :)